# Deletar um ID específico inserido como serialize em uma coluna no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

No meu db eu tenho uma coluna chamada `Range_ids`, que faço uma inserção de IDs usando a função `serialize`. Esses IDs ficam como um array, o problema é como eu posso fazer um `DELETE` do ID específico dentro da coluna.

```
//Usando a função serialize eu insiro esses ids 1052,1053..... em serie

+------------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id         | nome     | Range_ids                                  |
+------------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| 01         | Prod1    | a:2:{i:1052;s:4:"1052";i:1053;s:4:"1053";} |
| 02         | Prod2    | a:2:{i:1052;s:4:"1052";i:1053;s:4:"1053";} |
| 03         | Prod3    | a:2:{i:1052;s:4:"1052";i:1053;s:4:"1053";} |
+------------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

O problema é como eu faço para deletar um ID especifico na linha específica.
Exemplo: quero remover o numero 1052 da coluna `range_id` na linha 1

```
//Precisaria de Algo assim
<a href="del.php?id_range=1052">Deletar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Terias de fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
$num = "1052";
$sql = "SELECT range_ids FROM tabela";
if($query = $conn->query($sql)){
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $linha[] = $row["range_ids"];
}
}
//var_dump($linha);
$db_range = $linha;
if(is_array($db_range)){
    foreach($db_range as $range){
        $un_dbrange = unserialize($range);
        //var_dump($un_dbrange);
        foreach($un_dbrange as $key=>$value){
            if($value == $num){
                unset($un_dbrange[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<hr/>";
var_dump($un_dbrange);
?>
```

*Vês como não fica nada bonito ?*

No caso, para deletar uma linha específica, terias de forecer também a `id` da tabela, mas ainda assim continuariam a ser muitas instruções. De momento eu não sei porque estás a trabalhar com um campo *serializado*, mas, normalmente não se recomenda trabalhar com campos deste tipo, pois são difíceis de manusear, e obriga-nos a criar demasiadas rotinas.

Comment: Ola amigo pelo que eu entendi nesse script voce fez um unserialize que foi separar o array o 1052  mais oque eu queria como fazer o procedimento de deletar so esse 1052  algo DELETE FROM.....

Comment: Depois de separar o array _1052_, deves fazer um _UPDATE_ com o novo valor, para que a o valor da primeira linha seja modificado.